# I want to pass parameter select query in sql server storedprocedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
declare @process varchar(50) ,@id int
set @id=11
set @process='PRODUCTION'

update Tracking 
set TargetbyHour = (
    (
        select cast(replace(costbyhour, '.','')/1 as integer) 
        from Tracking 
        where  trackingid = @TrackingID
    ) /    
    (
        (select   @process 
         from [dbo].[BillingSheet] 
         where  id=@id
        )
    )  
)    
where  TrackingID=@TrackingID
```

This is the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PRODUCTION' to data type int.

Note: `PRODUCTION` is a table column name  datatype is `float`

Comment: if I enter PRODUCTION as manually it's working but I want to pass the parameter only

Comment: No, @process is a `varchar(50)`, that you happen to have set to the string `'PRODUCTION'`, when you `Select @process` you get the varchar(50).

Comment: Before you write a stored procedure that generates arbitrary TSQL based on an injected string, I'd recommend reading this reference http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: There is not a need to use dynamic SQL at all. You can [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) `[dbo].[BillingSheet]` then you can use a `WHERE` to filter out the `'PRODUCTION'` row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL - so

```
select   @process 
from [dbo].[BillingSheet] 
where  id=@id
```

Will simply return the value stored in the `@process` variable - in this case - `'PRODUCTION'`

If you have multiple columns with the same data type and you want to choose which one to select from, you can use case:

```
select case @process
       when 'PRODUCTION' then PRODUCTION
       when 'TEST' then TEST
       when 'DEV' then DEV
       end As val
from [dbo].[BillingSheet] 
where  id=@id
```

Please note that a case expression must return the same data type from all it's branches, so if the columns are of different data types, you must convert them to the best suited data type for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build dynamic sql and execute it.

```
declare @process varchar(50) ,@id int, @TrackingID INT
set @id=11
set @process='PRODUCTION'

DECLARE @SqlText  nvarchar(max)
SET @SqlText  = 'update Tracking 
set TargetbyHour = (
    (
        select cast(replace(costbyhour, ''.'','''')/1 as integer) 
        from Tracking 
        where  trackingid = @TrackingID
    ) /    
    (
        (select  ' + QUOTENAME(@process) + '
         from [dbo].[BillingSheet] 
         where  id=@id
        )
    )  
)    
where  TrackingID=@TrackingID'

DECLARE @paramlist  nvarchar(max)
SET @paramlist  = '@TrackingID INT,
                @id INT'


EXEC sp_executesql @SqlText, @paramlist, 
                @TrackingID ,
                @id
```

Comment: @ganesh but I wouldn't do that in a stored procedure, do it in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic SQL, see this

```
DECLARE @process VARCHAR(50) = 'PRODUCTION';
DECLARE @id INT  = 11;
DECLARE @cost FLOAT;

SELECT
            @cost = [Cost]
    FROM
            (
            SELECT
                        [Id],
                        [PRODUCTION],
                        [DEV],
                        [TEST]
                FROM
                        [dbo].[BillingSheet]
            ) P
        UNPIVOT
            (
                [Cost] FOR [Process] IN ([PRODUCTION],[DEV],[TEST])
            ) UP
    WHERE
            [Id] = @Id
        AND
            [Process] = @process;

UPDATE [Tracking] 
    SET
        [TargetbyHour] = CAST(REPLACE([costbyhour], '.','')/1 AS INT) / @cost
    FROM
            [Tracking] 
    WHERE
            [trackingid] = @TrackingID;
```

This approach `UNPIVOT`s `[dbo].[BillingSheet]` so the `'PRODUCTION'` value can be extracted using a normal `WHERE`.